# Cannot get mutual authentication with Keycloak and OpenLDAP working

Tags: ssl, keycloak, openldap

I've been attempting to get mutual authentication working between Keycloak and OpenLDAP. I've configured the truststore on Keycloak under security realms, which works. I can view the certificate on requests. I've also configured OpenLDAP's truststore/keystore and set it to demand a client certificate. When using `ldapsearch` I can provide Keycloak's cert which allows me to connect. I've also verified that Keycloak accepts OpenLDAP's cert by changing OpenLDAP to not demand a client certificate, which allows Keycloak to connect (albeit after fixing the truststore). At this point, it appears everything is fine except Keycloak doesn't present it's certificate while acting as a client, and I get the following error in OpenLDAP.

```
TLS trace: SSL3 alert write:fatal:handshake failure
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in error
TLS: can't accept: error:140890C7:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate.
```

Unfortunately I cannot share details about the configuration or environment beyond the above due to project constraints.